# SLF4J and Logback for non java log files

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

Can use SLF4J+Logback for non java applications log files ?
I mean if we have a log file named `e.g. non-java.log` can use `RollingFileAppender` for  rotate this file ?
Note : imagine `non-java.log` generated by C/C++ or golang application .
Note : I know we can use `syslog` (in linux) or other OS utils ,but I want to understand logback can do something like syslog.
there is any java library for manage non java log files ?
**UPDATE :**
I working on new Operating system named `JOS`. (not released yet)
https://github.com/Java-OS
My idea is completely replaces GNU project with Java utilities ,
Now i want to understand can manage os logs like `dmesg` or `syslog` with java base tools .

Comment: vote down without any description ??? really ????

Comment: You should explain what you want to achieve. Do you want something outside the C/C++/Golang application to "externally" rotate the log files?

Answer (score 0):

Slf4j and logback are written in java and solely for Java (or at least JVM based) languages:
They load java classes into JVM, they creat Java objects, manage memory in a sense that java objects do (no explicit descructors, relying on garbage collection) and so on and so forth.

Without java ecosystem (read jvm) its impossible to use these libraries.

The Log rotation is nothing but the code implemented in the relevant appender  of the library, namely appender that writes to file.
Just to avoid confusions in terms: an appender is like a channel that can handle logs in one concrete way, like write to file, send via socket, print to console, etc.

So if your application that produces the logs runs on top of JVM - no problem using these libraries, otherwise you should either find an appropriate library in your language or choice or roll your own implementation.